# Access module masked by variable name

Tags: python, namespaces

How do I access a module named x that I masked with a variable named x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `sys.modules[module_name]` ... and you should avoid masking module names: use wisely the `import` statement e.g. import XYZ as ABC.

You can also rely on using a more complete namespace "path" e.g. `os.path.xxx`

Comment: But what if it's `sys` that's masked? Also, using a namespace path won't help if e.g. `os` is no longer a module.

Comment: ... and also if XYZ is masked and ...  the point is: there are different ways to address the problem.

Answer (score 3):

don't name your variable `x` or use `import ... as` style.

```
>>> sys = 2
>>> import sys as s
>>> s
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>> sys
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import x as someotherx
```